# Why use series solution rather than variation of parameters?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

When should we use series solution to solve a general 2nd order ODE rather than the variation of parameters?

Could both methods be used to solve any 2nd order ODE or are there restrictions on when you can use each method?

Comment: You are talking about the homogeneous ones or the inhomogeneous ones?

Comment: I don't think they are for the same thing. You use variation of parameters to solve a non-homogeneous equation once all homogeneous solutions are known. The Frobenius method is a way to solve for homogeneous solutions.

Comment: @Tunococ I reread my text book and you can only use VOP when you are given the complementary solution and are required to find the particular solution. Series solutions allows you to solve for this complementary solution when your coefficients are non-constant.

Answer (score 1):

> Could both methods be used to solve any 2nd order ODE

There are **no** methods that can be used to solve any 2nd order ODE. Even if we restrict ourselves only to linear ODE (as you do without saying it). If you write down a random second-order linear ODE: say,
$$y''+e^{x}y'+\cos(x^2)\,y=\sin x$$
... don't expect much from any textbook method. The ODEs you see in your textbook are specially designed to be solvable by its methods, which may create the impression that these methods always work. (Of course, for linear equations with *constant* coefficients they do work.)

Back to the main question:

> When should we use series solution to solve a general 2nd order ODE rather than the variation of parameters?

To use the variation of parameters, you have to know  the solutions of homogeneous equation. What if you don't, like for the equation above?

The series method has the drawback that it only gives the solution as a series. But sometimes a series may be  what you want, when you don't expect any closed-form solution anyway. When the coefficients of the ODE and its free term can be expanded into power series, you can usually find at least a few terms of the power series of $y$ just by solving a system of linear equations (there are issues at singular points, as with [the Bessel equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function)). This may give a reasonable approximation to $y$ in the vicinity of the point of expansion. But don't expect to find a formula for coefficients of the entire series -- such things only happen in textbooks.